# Volatile and ArrayBlockingQueue and perhaps other concurrent objects

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, java.util.concurrent

I understand (or at least I think I do;) ) the principle behind `volatile` keyword.
When looking into `ConcurrentHashMap` source, you can see that all nodes and values are declared `volatile`, which makes sense because the value can be written/read from more than one thread:

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    volatile V val;
    volatile Node<K,V> next;
    ...
}
```

However, looking into `ArrayBlockingQueue` source, it's a plain array that is being updated/read from multiple threads:

```
private void enqueue(E x) {
    // assert lock.getHoldCount() == 1;
    // assert items[putIndex] == null;
    final Object[] items = this.items;
    items[putIndex] = x;
    if (++putIndex == items.length)
        putIndex = 0;
    count++;
    notEmpty.signal();
}
```

How is it guaranteed that the value inserted into `items[putIndex]` will be visible from another thread, providing that the element inside the array is not volatile (i know that declaring the array itself doesnt have any effect anyhow on the elements themselves) ? 
Couldn't another thread hold a cached copy of the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that `enqueue` is `private`. Look for all calls to it (`offer(E), offer(E, long, TimeUnit), put(E)`). Notice that every one of those looks like:

```
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    checkNotNull(e);
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        // Do stuff.
        enqueue(e);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

So you can conclude that **every call to `enqueue` is protected by a `lock.lock() ... lock.unlock()`** so you don't need `volatile` because `lock.lock/unlock` are also a memory barrier.

Comment: yes i noticed it but i had no clue that locking serves as memory barrier. I thought that synchronized does, but was not sure about lock. Are you sure? because the only thing lock() does is mark the current thread as the exclusive owner and set the internal state. I can't see how it is related to memory barrier

Comment: ok you're right, in the java doc it says the lock must provide same memory semantic as synchronized. so i wonder how it works internally. might it be that there is specific handling by the compiler for these locks?

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding volatile is not needed as all BlockingQueue implementations already have a locking mechanism unlike the `ConcurrentHashMap`. 
If you look at he public methods of the Queue you will find a `ReentrantLock` that guards for concurrent access.